# how to catch conversion of param in rescue and dont catch model errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have controller.rb as follows

```
def lesson
  params.require(:lesson_id)
  begin
    @result = @user.lesson_details(Integer(params[:lesson_id]),
                              params[:lesson_name]
    head :ok
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
end
```

I am testing using postman http://localhost:3001/DB/DB_id/users/user_id/books/lesson/lesson_id?lesson_name='test'
How do i wrap the conversion of the param lesson_id in rescue so i don't catch any underlying model's errors as well?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to wrap it in an if:

```
def lesson
  if params[:lesson_id] && params[:lesson_name]
    @result = @user.lesson_details(params[:lesson_id]),
                                   params[:lesson_name]
    head :ok
  else
    render_error :bad_request, 'Your message here'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pachonk. I am testing with postman and when i try your solution for id value abc or nil i get argument error

Comment: I have changed it to require name too. Please try.

Comment: same error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: calling in postman http://localhost:3001/DB/DB_id/users/user_id/books/lesson/lesson_id?lesson_name='test'

Comment: Can you please update your question to include this data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139065/discussion-between-user7354632781-and-pachonk).

Answer (score 0):

You can just rescue nil on @result.

```
def lesson
  @result = @user.lesson_details(params[:lesson_id]), params[:lesson_name] rescue nil 
  if @result 
    head :ok
  else
    render_error :bad_request, 'Your message here'
  end
end
```

Or you could use the rescue clause without ArgumentError

```
def lesson
  params.require(:lesson_id)
  begin
    @result = @user.lesson_details(Integer(params[:lesson_id]),
                              params[:lesson_name]
    head :ok
  rescue => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain in your 2nd solution, why remove ArgumentError? does that mean ArgumentErrors come only from model and cant happen in controller? because if i test with say lesson_id = abc i get same error (invalid value for integer() abc) with and without having ArgumentError in controller